# My question was put on hold

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[My question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/466815/) was put on hold because "homework-like".

I would like some clarification on this please. I am not asking anybody to do a conversion of me, I am asking whether the conversion mol/mm3 <-> mol/L is always the same and independent of other features such as temperature, pressure, etc. Can somebody please explain why this is not appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have been a little bit to hasty. The question has now been (in my opinion, rightfully) reopened.

Answer (score 4):

Question is now re-opened. I first overlooked the conceptional question. I would suggest to change title to e.g.

> *Is 1 liter always equal to 1 cubic decimeter, independently of temperature, pressure, etc?*

to high-light the conceptional question.

Comment: Suggestion taken, title revised, thanks!